# Cannot connect to RDS dbinstance (AWS) to access the database in an application

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a `rds` `db instanc`e named `testdbinstance` which has an endpoint `testdbinstance.cwucj0efbeuu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306`.I have created a `rds user` and `password`. I have imported the database in rdsdatabase.

I have an application written in php and mysql. i am trying to access the application using the rds database.

I have a `db.ini` file that has field `dbhostname,dbname,dbusername and dbpasswd`. I have replaced with the appropriate fields.

But still I am getting this error :

[image]

Kindly help me resolve this error

Comment: try connecting with MySQL CLI first to ensure that connectivity is fine. The syntax is `mysql -h<hostname> -u<username> -p<password>`. If you fail to connect using MySQL cli, then resolve the connectivity issues first.

Comment: Im able to connect and see the database and tables

Comment: Ok, then this is more of PHP code issue. I am not good with PHP .but could you show us what is line 229 which is mentioned in error message ?

Comment: now i m not getting any error but a blank page !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @slayedbylucifer : i have q query, if i have database imported on rds then is it required to have the database locally in order to make sure that the application runs ??? or i can delete the database residing on the local box ???

Comment: It really depends how you are accessing the DB. If you have DB imported on RDS **AND** you are able to access RDS via your application, then there is no need for the DB to be present locally.

Comment: also if im using MySQL engine in RDS then do i need to install MySQL on my local machine ?

Comment: No, you don't have to. All you need is a RDS and your local application. And ensure that the connectivity is fine. No other MySQL is needed.

Comment: how how will i import database using MySQl CLI. like i have to use certain commands then how to do that ?? without MySQL ???

Comment: check this: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/. You may need to install MySLQ CLI (client).

Comment: yeah that is what my query is do I need to install mysql server ???

Comment: im verifying it will share the results with you !!!

Comment: i have one question i have installed the mysql client and im configuring the RDS db engine then what should i select in the version of mysql ???

Comment: I am not aware of this. I always just use MySQL CLI to connect to the RDS using the syntax which I have mentioned in my very 1st comment.

Comment: I have this page database.php and i have installed only mysql client on my machine, when i execute this php page it shows me the code not the data !!!

Comment: what is this MYSQL cli tools

Comment: hey man, you are doing things wrong way. You need to use something like ODBC/JDBC (or whatever that PHP supports) driver for PHP to connect to MYSQL. MySQ CLI is a standalone client which has nothing to do with any other languages. Check this: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mysql_database.php Again don't confuse MySQL CLI with PHP at all.

Comment: what are the possible use cases in RDS